# DataTransfer.mozSetDataAt() throws SecurityError

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I tried to used [`DataTransfer.mozSetDataAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/mozSetDataAt) method in a jsfiddle [script](https://jsfiddle.net/oh3ymnke/1/) and it throws

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

Why is that? Is this method for extensions only (not allowed to be used in regular web pages)?

Used browser: Firefox 55.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to throw here is your use of the private `'application/x-moz-file'` data type.

If you use the real MIME type (`'image/png'`) then it won't throw and your file will be added in the dataTransfer object :

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const image = document.querySelector('img');
let file = null;
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.execCommand('copy') 
})

document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  event.clipboardData.mozSetDataAt('image/png', file, 0);
  console.log(event.clipboardData.files)
})

// to avoid the big dataURI in post
fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Mozilla_Firefox_3.5_logo_256.png/145px-Mozilla_Firefox_3.5_logo_256.png")
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => file = new File([blob], 'firefox.png'));
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Mozilla_Firefox_3.5_logo_256.png/145px-Mozilla_Firefox_3.5_logo_256.png" width="20" height="20"/>

<button>copy</button>
```